# How do I make a drop down menu on the title bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ubuntu-18.04

I'm creating a simple gui application in python. I know the existing drop down menu option in tkinter but I want it to appear on the title bar. Similar to what you can find on the gnome-calculator in ubuntu18.04 (selecting between modes). How to achieve this using python3 tkinter?

Comment: You have to prevent the window manager from drawing a title bar and use tkinter facilities to fake one (if you think of it, this is what Gnome applications tipically do).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a frameless window using `self.overrideredirect(True)` and put a widget representing the title bar on the top of the window. Put your dropdown into that widget. Simple example:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Example")
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.title_bar = ttk.Combobox(values=["Mode 1", "Mode 2"])
        self.title_bar.set("Mode 1")
        self.title_bar.state(["readonly"])
        self.title_bar.pack()

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Note that in this example the window is not visible in the taskbar. See [Tkinter, Windows: How to view window in windows task bar which has no title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786337/tkinter-windows-how-to-view-window-in-windows-task-bar-which-has-no-title-bar)

Comment: When I execute your code the following error is raised: `_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name r` from the line `self.title_bar.state("readonly")` — I've got the same behavior with the system Python and with Anaconda's one.

Comment: @gboffi Thank you for telling that. I'll fix the code.

Comment: I tried to execute your code because I fear that your window interacts BADLY with the wm, have you checked that?

Comment: Now that you have "fixed" your code I can tell that your window DOES interact badly with the window manager.

Comment: This is just a minimal example. It could have a lot more features.

Comment: This is a wrong example.

Comment: @gboffi I added a link to a related question that explains how to make the window appear in the taskbar.