# WS_THICKFRAME=0 leads to unexpected padding in x-axis

Tags: windows, tkinter

I'm trying to write a splash window containing a canvas with an image inside. I want to remove titlebar and borders without using `overrideredirect(1)`. I searched and found some solutions ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68621773/22543630)) that do remove the titlebar and borders. But I found unexpected padding in window.

I want the window to be in the exact same size with the canvas containing the image. I don't want titlebar, borders and paddings. Here is a copy of my codes:

```py
import tkinter
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk
from ctypes import windll
from typing import Callable, Tuple

# Windows Section
GWL_STYLE = -16
GWLP_HWNDPARENT = -8
WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000
WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000
WS_BORDER = 0x00800000
GetWindowLongPtrW = windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrW
SetWindowLongPtrW = windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW


def get_window_handle(root) -> int:
    root.update_idletasks()
    # This gets the window's parent same as `ctypes.windll.user32.GetParent`
    return GetWindowLongPtrW(root.winfo_id(), GWLP_HWNDPARENT)


def calcIMG_MAX_WHTuple(original_WH: Tuple[int, int], frame_WH: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    scale_w, scale_h = [frame_WH[i] / original_WH[i] for i in range(0, 2)]
    scale = min(scale_w, scale_h)
    retv = (round(original_WH[i] * scale) for i in range(2))
    return retv


resizeImgIntoFrame: Callable[[PIL.Image.Image, Tuple[int, int]], PIL.Image.Image] = \
    (lambda img, framesize: img.resize(calcIMG_MAX_WHTuple(original_WH=(img.width, img.height),
                                                           frame_WH=framesize)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = (640, 360)
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.configure(bg='blue')
    splash_img = PIL.Image.open('some_screenshot.png')
    splash_photoimg = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizeImgIntoFrame(splash_img, size))
    canvas_size = (splash_photoimg.width(), splash_photoimg.height())
    print(canvas_size)

    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=canvas_size[0], height=canvas_size[1],
                            highlightthickness=0)

    hwnd: int = get_window_handle(root)
    style: int = GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
    style &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME )
    SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style)
    canvas.pack()
    # canvas.grid(column=0, row=0)

    root.update_idletasks()
    print(root.config())
    print(root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height())
    print(root.winfo_reqwidth(), root.winfo_reqheight())
    root.mainloop()
```

The first line of the output (`print(canvas_size)`)

```
(640, 360)
```

The last two lines of the output:

```
656 360
640 360
```

Here is a photo:
[Actual Window Appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szknl.png)

I'm curious about where `656` came out and why it's not `640`.
If I remove `WS_THICKFRAME` in the codes, `656` will be decreased to `642`. If I remove `WS_THICKFRAME` and `WS_CAPTION` in the codes, the two width values will be equal. But if I really do this, the titlebar and the borders are back.

I'm working on Windows 10 and I don't need a Linux solutions.

What should I do?