# overrideredirect(true) lost the icon in the taskbar, I want to restore it

Tags: python, tkinter, tr

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.overrideredirect(True)

window.geometry("360x550")
window.title("NT-Sounds | Tiếng cười Livestream")
window.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "gray")


canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = 360, height = 550, bg="white", highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()


window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

This is my code, how to show icon app on taskbar? Anyone help me please!!!

I have tried many ways, asked many forums but I can't solve it. I want to hide the title bar but don't want to lose the icon in the taskbar.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786337/tkinter-windows-how-to-view-window-in-windows-task-bar-which-has-no-title-bar) may help if your platform is Windows.

Comment: You can't restore the taskbar if using `window.overrideredirect(True)`.