How to remove the title bar of a tkinter application without making it full-screen or removing the taskbar icon?
I'm developing a tkinter application and would like to remove the title bar while keeping the window border intact and preserving the taskbar icon. Setting the window to full-screen or hiding the taskbar icon isn't desirable for my application.
I've tried solutions involving overrideredirect(True), but this removes both the title bar and the window border. Is there a way to achieve this on Windows (and ideally cross-platform) while still allowing the window to be resizable and draggable?
Edit:
from tkinter import Tk
mroot = Tk()
mroot.title("Welcome!")
mroot.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')


This question is similar to: Remove titlebar without overrideredirect() using Tkinter?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

_tkinter.TclError: bad attribute "-type": must be -alpha, -transparentcolor, -disabled, -fullscreen, -toolwindow, or -topmost

Please post the code where others can help with your problem.

There is no way to do it with just using tkinter unless you create a small (normal) window and make sure it's always behind your main one. That trick isn't perfect but if you want, you can call WinAPI functions like this

@TheLizzard Thanks I think it is a good work actually.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30819099/291641. The -type option mentioned above is only for X11 as it sets the X11 Extended Window Manager Hint for the window.
