# Make a GUI that doesn't show in taskbar

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display a tkinter window (with an image,in my case) that doesn't show on the taskbar. I've already tried using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128434/removing-windows-from-the-taskbar-windows-7), but the person that answered didn't provide an example so I am unable to replicate it (and I'm using Windows 10 so maybe that is another factor to consider).

My code is here. I am using Python 3.5

```
from tkinter import Toplevel, Tk, Label, PhotoImage

win = Tk()

win.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
win.iconify()

window = Toplevel(win)
window.geometry("500x500+100+100")
window.overrideredirect(1)

photo = PhotoImage(file="testfile.png")

label = Label(window, image=photo)
label.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked question contained an interesting comment recommending to reverse what was done in [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30819099/3545273). Along with this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7128621/3545273) that explains that what is needed is just to set the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style, a simple example is:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ctypes import windll

GWL_EXSTYLE=-20
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW=0x00000080

def set_toolwindow(root):
    hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
    style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
    style = style | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
    res = windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
    # re-assert the new window style
    root.wm_withdraw()
    root.after(10, lambda: root.wm_deiconify())

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("AppWindow Test")
    button = ttk.Button(root, text='Exit', command=lambda: root.destroy())
    button.place(x=10,y=10)
    #root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.after(10, lambda: set_toolwindow(root))
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Credits should remain to authors of the two linked posts. This just uses both to provide an example to OP.

Comment: Thanks! I am a noobie and this example helped me a lot, but I don't know how to transform my code to integrate that functionality. I suppose I need to introduce my code into a "def main():", but I don't know how to do that. If you could please help me in that regard, I'd be very grateful

Comment: @nicochulo: `def main(): ... if __name__ == '__main__': main()` if a common idiom to allow a script to be executed as a stand alone program or included in another script. It has nothing to do with your current problem. The part of interest for you is `set_toolwindow`.

Comment: I've tried it and it works perfectly! I just added that "def set_toolwindow(root):" and all of its code and I replaced all "root" with "win" (because in my case those are called win). I'll upvote and mark as answer