# how to hide top level window icon from the task bar without hiding its border

Tags: python, tkinter

i am making tkinter window and another one as top level but i want when the top level window is displayed only one icon in the task bar which is main window icon not the top level one

I already used overrideredirect(1), it works but it also hid top level border including title bar

```
w = tk.Tk()
w.title('main')
w.geometry('300x300')

def c():
    t = tk.Toplevel()
    t.title('toplevel') 
    t.geometry('100x100')
    # t.overrideredirect(1) 
    t.mainloop()
b = tk.Button(w,text='click',command=c)
b.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi! Adam. Please show us the code or just the specific part from which we can understand what you really trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm on Mac so I can't this as it has way of displaying icon though you can do one thing try putting a blank(transparent) icon on your top-level window LINK = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550050/removing-the-tk-icon-on-a-tkinter-window. Or try doing `overrideredirect(0)` and `overrideredirect(1)` just after you set it false. I will not guarantee.

Comment: Relevant [making-tkinter-multiple-windows-have-one-icon-in-the-task-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760753/making-tkinter-multiple-windows-have-one-icon-in-the-task-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `.transient()` does exactly what you want, it will remove the toplevel icon from the taskbar:

```
import tkinter as tk
w = tk.Tk()
w.title('main')
w.geometry('300x300')

def c():
    t = tk.Toplevel()
    t.title('toplevel') 
    t.geometry('100x100')
    t.transient(w) 

b = tk.Button(w, text='click', command=c)
b.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

By the way, you only need to call `mainloop()` once, calling it again in the function `c` is useless.

Comment: This is exactly what I've looked for a long time! This answer should have more attention!